# How do I expand the state $| x \rangle$ in terms of another orthogonal basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, representation-theory

In my quantum mechanics textbook it says that the relation between the basis $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ is given by:

$\langle p | x \rangle = \Large \frac{e^{-ip x/ \hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \, .$

However, i'm not sure how to go about proving this relation. My idea was that the eigenstates of momentum can be written as below:

$\phi(x,p) = \Large \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} e^{-ipx/\hbar},$

which form an orthogonal basis.

But, we can expand any state, $|\text{state}\rangle$, in terms of the othorgonal basis right? **So is my notation below correct for the expansion of the state $| x \rangle$** ?

$|x\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) |p'\rangle dp'$

If it were correct then the following would also be correct?

Using the fact that $\langle p | p' \rangle = \delta(p - p')$, $\langle p | x \rangle$ can be computed:

\begin{align}
\langle p | x \rangle
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) \langle p | p' \rangle dp' \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) \delta(p - p') dp' \\
=& \phi(p, x) \\
=& \Large \frac{e^{-ip x/ \hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}
\end{align}
as required.

Does the logic work here?

Comment: These manipulations are correct, but sort of trivial, because $\phi(x, p)$ as you wrote it is _defined_ to be equal to $\langle p | x \rangle$. So you took the definition the other direction.

Comment: If you want to derive it from scratch, you need to start from a different assumption, such as $[x, p] = i \hbar$.

Comment: Ahh. Okay I see. I will start from the commutation relationship first then and try again later :) Thank you

Comment: Good luck! It's pretty hard though; I don't know how to do it totally rigorously. If you're doing an intro QM course, it probably just takes the $\phi(x, p)$ you said as an axiom.